# Is possible to connect two wireless devices if they are on different subnets?

Tags: android, networking, multicast, access-point

I'm working on an android app. Lets assume that i have 4 devices (smartphones), two of them are accesspoints and to both of them are connect a device, obvously they are connect via wireless.

So the fact is that i need a way to send data from one subnet to the other, i tried to use multicast (using jmdns library) but without success.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.MulticastSocket;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import com.classes.domain.NetworkProperties;
    import com.classes.domain.Settings;

    public class MulticastSender {

        private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = null;

        public static final String MC_ADDRESS = "226.2.2.3";
        public static final int MC_PORT = 8888;
        public static final int MAX_LEN = 1024;

        public static void startExecutor() {

            scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

            // remove final and uncomment line above if you wanna force automatic
            // start
            // final Runnable multicastServer = new Runnable() {
            Runnable multicastServer = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    multicastSender();
                }
            };

            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(multicastServer, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        public static void multicastSender() {
            MulticastSocket socket = null;
            InetAddress address = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            int ttl = 1;
            String sendData = null;
            byte[] sendBytes = null;

            try {
                socket = new MulticastSocket();
                socket.setTimeToLive(ttl);

                address = InetAddress.getByName(MC_ADDRESS);

                NetworkProperties.retrieveNetworkProperties();
                String ip = NetworkProperties.localIPv4Address;
                int port = NetworkProperties.applicationPort;

                sendData = ip + "-" + port;
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sendData.getBytes());
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                while ((sendData = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    sendBytes = sendData.getBytes();

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendBytes, sendBytes.length, address, MC_PORT);
                    socket.send(packet);

                }

                socket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }



package com.classes.domain;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

public class MulticastReceiver {

    public static final String MC_ADDRESS = "226.2.2.3";
    public static final int MC_PORT = 8888;
    public static final int MAX_LEN = 1024;

    public static void multicastReceiver(Context context) {

        MulticastSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket packet = null;
        InetAddress address = null;
        WifiManager.MulticastLock lock = null;

        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi != null) {
            lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("AllowMulticast");
            lock.acquire();
        }

        try {
            socket = new MulticastSocket(MC_PORT);
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);

            address = InetAddress.getByName(MC_ADDRESS);
            socket.joinGroup(address);

            while (true) {

                byte[] buf = new byte[MAX_LEN];
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

                socket.receive(packet);

                String msg = new String(buf, 0, packet.getLength());
//              System.out.println("From " + packet.getAddress() + " Msg : "
//                      + msg);
//              System.out.println("Received " + packet.getLength()
//                      + " bytes from " + packet.getAddress() + ": "
//                      + new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength()));

                String temp = msg;

/*
REPLACE THIS PART WITH RECEIVED DATA DO WHAT YOU NEED
                if (temp.indexOf("-") != -1) {
                    String[] result = temp.split("-");
                    String ip = result[0];
                    String port = result[1];


                    Settings settings = Settings.loadSettings(context);
                    settings.setIP(ip);
                    settings.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
                    try {
                        settings.Save(context);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
*/

                break;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            socket.leaveGroup(address);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (lock.isHeld()) {
            lock.release();
            lock = null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry if i annoy you again, but  the import com.classes.domain is from an external jar? Thank you

Comment: No, those are mine classes, import com.classes.domain.NetworkProperties; is used for retrieving network info (IP, subnet mask, and some additional info from different OS, Linux, Win) and  Settings is class for handling multiple SharedPreferences keys, so you can remove both of them and replace following data with some of yours


/* remove this and replace with yours */
NetworkProperties.retrieveNetworkProperties();
String ip = NetworkProperties.localIPv4Address;
int port = NetworkProperties.applicationPort;
sendData = ip + "-" + port;

Comment: Really sorry but it didn't works for me. If smartphone and pc are in the same network it works good, but if my smartphone is connect to another network, it didn't receives the packet. Thank you.

Comment: This code works for you if you are on same subnet? That's strange since basic idea of multicast is sending and receiving data to same address that multicast users are joined in. It seems to me that this is more of a router problem, whoever routes traffic, either smartphone or real router. Can you add some of yours code snippet that you use, maybe I can help

Comment: Yes if they are on the same subnet it works. It's strange also for me the fact that on different subnets it doesn't work. I copied the code you posted here.

Comment: Well, then it is most certainly problem in your router, it doesn't support multicast to different subnets or it is disabled (this is default option on most routers). You can try to login to your router and find something like Multicast, VLAN or even Subnet Directed Broadcast option

Comment: The problem is that i don't have a real router, but just a smartphone in accesspoint mode.

Comment: In that case I can't help you :(

Answer (score 1):

I done something similar between pc and smartphone using multicast without any library, just MulticastSocket class in Android and Java backend, did you try that?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't receive the packet, can you please share the code? Thanks a lot!